# MDL: Changing Color of Indeterminate Progress Bar?

Tags: material-design, material-design-lite

How do I change the color of an indeterminate progress bar in Material Design Lite?

I would like the bar to use the accent color I have chosen (pink) when I invoked

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
```

This is the line for the progress bar currently:

```
<div class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

I have tried adding mdl-color--pink-500 and mdl-color-text--pink-500 to the class, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. Apparently `mdl-progress` uses the theme color for display & there's no straight-forward way to change that. I ended up creating an additional class `mdl-progress-red` which I attach to the `mdl-progress` only so that I can set the color of the child elements. Below you have the CSS for red `rgb(255,0,0)`. If you want to change the color, just replace `rgb(255,0,0)` with your desired color everywhere in the style below.

```
.mdl-progress-red > .progressbar {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.mdl-progress-red > .bufferbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.7), rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,0,0), rgb(255,0,0));
}

.mdl-progress-red > .auxbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.9), rgba(255,255,255, 0.9)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,0,0), rgb(255,0,0));
}
```

And then, to apply the color to your progress bar - you just specify the new class name like so:

```
<div class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate mdl-progress-red" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've also come across the same issue when trying out Material design. Marius is correct in stating:

> Ran into the same problem. Apparently mdl-progress uses the theme color for display & there's no straight-forward way to change that.

I've tried his answer on codepen and it didn't work for me, but I've managed to get it working by adding `!important` to the CSS. See below, based on the Material progress bar example with a second -- custom coloured bar -- based on Marius' solution:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple MDL Progress Bar -->
    <div id="p1" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress"></div>
    <br></br>
    <div id="p2" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress-red"</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
}

.mdl-progress-red > .bufferbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.7), rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,0,0), rgb(255,0,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-red > .auxbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.9), rgba(255,255,255, 0.9)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,0,0), rgb(255,0,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-red > .progressbar {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('#p1').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });

document.querySelector('#p2').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

this code create four progress bar with red, orange, yellow and green color

```
.mdl-progress-red > .bufferbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.7), rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,0,0), rgb(255,0,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-red > .auxbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.9), rgba(255,255,255, 0.9)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,0,0), rgb(255,0,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-red > .progressbar {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}

.mdl-progress-orange > .bufferbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,227,199, 0.7), rgba(255,227,199, 0.7)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,145,0), rgb(255,145,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-orange > .auxbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,227,199, 0.9), rgba(255,227,199, 0.9)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,145,0), rgb(255,145,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-orange > .progressbar {
    background-color: rgb(255,145,0) !important;
}

.mdl-progress-yellow > .bufferbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,206, 0.7), rgba(255,255,206, 0.7)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240,220,0), rgb(240,220,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-yellow > .auxbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,206, 0.9), rgba(255,255,206, 0.9)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240,220,0), rgb(240,220,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-yellow > .progressbar {
    background-color: rgb(240,220,0) !important;
}

.mdl-progress-green > .bufferbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(214,255,214, 0.7), rgba(214,255,214, 0.7)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0,153,0), rgb(0,153,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-green > .auxbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(214,255,214, 0.9), rgba(214,255,214, 0.9)), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0,153,0), rgb(0,153,0))  !important;
}

.mdl-progress-green > .progressbar {
    background-color: rgb(0,153,0) !important;
}
```

example four progress bar

```
<div id="p1" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress-red"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="p2" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress-orange"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="p3" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress-yellow"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="p4" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress-green"></div>
<script>
document.querySelector('#p1').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });

document.querySelector('#p2').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });
document.querySelector('#p3').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });
document.querySelector('#p4').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(44);
  });

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is only code. Please explain a little bit what you are doing to help the people understand your solution.